Wordpress issue in popup on button click
In this,There is one add to cart button. I have added whatsapp enquiry button.now I want to popup on button click.
Pop-up is generated but on page not on button click.
Please guide me for this.
Website Url: https://manufact.srkwebappinnovations.com/product-new/
I am go through with css js but not working or I am getting correct way.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? - no. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].
